# Get interface name of active network (API 21)

Tags: android, android-networking

I need to get the interface name of the active network (e.g. `wlan0`) in API 21.

In API 23 I can do:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Network activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork();
if (activeNetwork != null)
{
    LinkProperties linkProperties = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(activeNetwork);
    String name = linkProperties.getInterfaceName();
    ...
}
```

However `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()` is only available in API 23 and above.

Is there an acceptable solution compatible with API 21?

I have come up with the following which iterates through all networks and compares `NetworkInfo.toString()` (because comparing by reference or value doesn't work). It seems to work but it also feels like a huge hack:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (activeNetworkInfo != null)
{
    Network[] networks = connectivityManager.getAllNetworks();
    for (Network network : networks)
    {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(network);
        if (networkInfo.toString().equals(activeNetworkInfo.toString()))
        {
            LinkProperties linkProperties = connectivityManager.getLinkProperties(network);
            String name = linkProperties.getInterfaceName();
            ...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated.